# How can I use api gateway stages via cloudformation or sam?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam-cli

I am using `AWS SAM` to deploy my lambda and api gateway. Below is my template yaml file:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  sam-app

  Sample SAM Template for sam-app

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: post

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

Lambda function and API gateway will be available after run `sam deploy`. I noticed that it creates two stages in API gateway `Stage` and `Prod`. I wonder how I can make use of the feature of `Stages`? I think the reason to provide different stages is for testing the API deployment before go to `Prod`. But there is no point to deploy to all stages altogether via SAM cli. Is there a best practise I can have a look how to use this feature? How can I deploy to a singe stage first before deploying to Prod?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically what you would do is set the stage variable for the API in the template (maybe getting it through SSM parameter store, or just passing it through manually). Then, you would deploy the template as stage = "dev", and stage = "prod", as two separate deployments.

Here is an example (notice the "Stage" parameter, and then the !Sub ${Stage} in the API path):

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  sam-app

  Sample SAM Template for sam-app

Parameters:
  Stage:
    Type: String
    Default: Dev  #you would change this for dev/prod

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: post

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${Stage}/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

You can then use [UsagePlans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-usageplan.html) per stage, or different API keys per stage to better manage your API

Comment: If I pass `stage` as a parameter then I will need to have two lambda functions for each stage right? Otherwise, if the lambda function is updated, it also impacts all API stages.

Comment: You would have a single Lambda for each stage, as in one for each template deployment. You could also specify the Lambda function name in the template and sub in the stage as well. If you want to share the same Lambda (which technically with dev/prod being separated you would want a separate Lambda also) you could have the Lambda in a separate template, and the API in a separate one, both pointing to the same Lambda

Comment: Hi @Deiv — thanks for this answer. I seem to be having trouble however, maybe I am missing something, but I've tried the above (and i've tried with an explicit API resource with `StageName` property) and every time I deploy (`Prod`, `Test`, `Dev`, `Foo`) the previous stage is simply overwritten. Am I missing a detail here?

Comment: You have to run it as a separate CloudFormation deployment with a new stage, otherwise it will get overwritten. CloudFormation will re-set the state to the current "Stage" value. The trick is to have a pipeline that deploys multiple CloudFormation stacks, each with its own "Stage" variable

Comment: It created Stage, Prod though I set Stage is dev